# Como dejar activo un Servidor Nodejs Con Express

Tags: nodejs, express

tengo una pregunta, tengo una web full stack hecha con Reactjs y Nodejs con Express, con MYSQL como base de datos, para esto cree una instancia VM de Google Cloud en la sección de Compute Engine para poder desplegar mi servidor y pude conseguir que se ejecute perfectamente y conectarlo con el Front-End  junto con la base de datos, la cuestión es que entro a la carpeta desde SSH y abrí el servidor y corre excelente, mi problema es que cuando cierro la pagina y dejo el server corriendo normal sin tener la ventana de google cloud ni de el SSH abierto, deja de funcionarme y tengo que volver a entrar a la consola SSH para poder iniciarlo nuevamente, busque e intente hacer que se inicie de manera automática cuando inicio el VM configurando desde el terminal como para que ejecute la función de manera automática para que se prenda el servidor y funciona, reinicio la instancia y se inicia solo pero pasa lo mismo que antes al rato de dejarlo corriendo deja de estar funcional y tengo que volver a iniciarlo manualmente luego de unos minutos, hay alguna forma de hacer que funcione sin que se corte ?